# Calculate how many times an Excel workbook is opened

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to calculate how many times an Excel workbook is opened. Every time anyone opens the workbook, that counts as 1 open and the the number of times should be incremented by 1.

I want to know this to check the efficiency and usefulness of the different reports I created, to see which one works and which is a waste of time and nobody would bat an eye on it.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Add something to the `Workbook_Open` event that reads and writes to an external text file, or even an INI file. But keep in mind no matter how you approach this, there are many ways the count will end up inaccurate in the long run. Someone might open it while holding down shift to disable macros. Someone might save it as a new name, and then that copy will get counted too.

Comment: I think that other way is to hide the counter inside the workbook to `xlSheetVeryHidden` sheet, check the file name and reset or increment the counter (e.g. original file name can be saved as constant and checked each time, if it is new - reset the counter), but still - there is a high risk of switched off macro as braX noted above.

Comment: You could use an addin that checks when workbooks are opened doing the same as @braX solution.  This would stop the shift, but bring in not running the add in to bypass, addin would allow single log to count all files opening if necessary.  But fully agree, open to issues either way.

Comment: Now i'm curious as to why you would want to know this information. After all, maybe there is something you can do to meet your end goal instead of actually counting how many times it is opened. Perhaps add to your question before it gets closed.

Comment: For example, lets say the location of the file was hidden, and the only way it could be opened was by running a script where the user entered a password to open it. Macros would have to be enabled then, so the only real way to bypass it would be if the person knew how to access and read your VBA code. (Again, still an imperfect solution)

Comment: @braX I want to know this to check the efficiency and usefulness of the different reports I created, to see which one works and which is a waste of time and nobody would bat an eye on it.

Comment: Well as long as you can accept it not being 100% accurate and reliable, the above solutions are do-able. If all you want is just a general idea used to compare to other almost-accurate numbers you would be fine. Although in this case, tracking multiple files, I would want to put the counts in a database for easy comparison.

Comment: And just to add... just because someone would open it to see what it does, that wouldn't necessarily mean that they found it useful.

Comment: VBA is not the right tool to check how many times the file was accessed. There are some paid applications like NETWRIX AUDITOR which can do what you want.

Comment: Using a database to track their actions, you could know when they opened it, when they closed it, and using environment variables - who it was, which machine they used to open it... all possible factors in determining its usefulness.

Comment: I would save the count under a name in Workbook.Names, increment upon the Workbook_Open event and autosave the new count. Won't be fully accurate as most of these answers are but the count will be tied to the individual workbook so copying/renaming etc shouldn't have such an effect on it

Comment: Have found a quick and dirty solution with VBA and wanted to share. Quite bulletproof. Too bad the question is closed. *sigh